# Cчитать переменную с textbox1 в заголовочном файле

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, c++-cli, textbox

Необходимо считать переменную с `textbox1`, но не знаю как это сделать.

```
el->d = Convert::ToDouble(Form1->textBox1->Text);
```

При попытке считать так выдает ошибку. В заголовочном файле форму подключил `#include "Form1.h"`.
Ошибка: Error: использование имени типа не допускается

Comment: Какую ошибку? Добавьте информацию в вопрос.

Comment: Ошибка: 
Error: использование имени типа не допускается

Answer (score 1):

`el->d` - что из себя представляет?
У Вас `Form1` скорее всего имя класса.
Если вы пытаетесь это вызвать внутри класса, то используйте `this->textBox1->Text`.
Если вне класса, то вместо `Form1` подставьте имя объекта этого класса.

Comment: А им`я объекта не подскажете?

Answer (score 0):

Здесь Form1 - это имя типа (класса) формы.
А обращаться нужно к объекту класса.
Где-то в программе должна быть объявлена переменная класса Form1, например так:

```
    Form1^ form = gcnew Form1();
```

далее можно будет получить значение textbox1 таким образом:

```
    System::String^ text = form->textbox1->Text;
```

Если обращение к textbox1 происходит внутри класса Form1, то вместо вместо имени переменной form используется this:

```
    System::String^ text = this->textbox1->Text;
```

При преобразовании в тип double следует учитывать, что текстовое поле может содержать произвольный текст и не всегда он может быть преобразован в число с плавающей точкой.
Поэтому делать это нужно так:

```
    try
    {
        auto d = System::Convert::ToDouble(form->textbox1->Text);
    }
    catch (FormatException e) 
    {
        // Обработка исключения;
    }
    catch (OverflowException e) 
    {
        // Обработка исключения;
    }
```